# Code doesn't run inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

im having a weird problem with my JQuery code.
Im trying to change a CSS attribute, to some element on the page.

this is the code that I tried runing and worked:

```
$("#player").css({
    "width" : "+=10"
});
```

My problem is when I try using this code from a function, it dosnt work.

this is the function:

```
   function change_elem_size (elemID,whatToChange,value) {
     $('#' + elemID).css({
        whatToChange : value
     });
   }
```

this is how I call the function:

```
function move_right (elemID,event) {
    $(document).keydown(function(event){
       change_elem_size(elemID,"width","+=10");
       });
}


    $(document).ready(function(){

      move_right("player",event);
    });
```

Why cant I use a function to change a css attribute?

(sorry for my english)

Comment: Why is this question being down voted? He shows effort and code and asks a clear question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you probebly right, but in chrome the code worked with '"width","+=10"'

Comment: @samy Yes, it works with the double quotes; you don't have those in the question, though, and the lack of them is the problem.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist oh i see! my mistake when i opened the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The left-hand side of a property initializer inside an object initializer (the bit before the `:`) is always a literal, never a variable. So this code:

```
function change_elem_size (elemID,whatToChange,value) {
    $('#' + elemID).css({
        whatToChange : value
    });
}
```

..sets the property `whatToChange`, it doesn't use the value of the variable to set a property name. To do that, don't use an object:

```
function change_elem_size (elemID,whatToChange,value) {
   $('#' + elemID).css(whatToChange, value);
}
```

...or optionally use an object, but use bracketed notation so that the *value* of `whatToChange` becomes the property name. To do that, you have to construct the object first, then add the property to it (you can't do it with an object initializer):

```
function change_elem_size (elemID,whatToChange,value) {
    var change = {};
    change[whatToChange] = value;
    $('#' + elemID).css(change);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> Why cant I use a function to change a css attribute?

You can. What you **can't** do is use a dynamic key for an object literal. That means when you do:

```
{
    whatToChange : value
}
```

it treats `whatToChange` *as the name of the property*, not as a variable that contains a value that should be the name of the property. You'll have to do this:

```
function change_elem_size (elemID,whatToChange,value) {
    var options = {}
    options[whatToChange] = value;
    $('#' + elemID).css(options);
}
```